# Выборочное добавление класса через JS

Tags: javascript

Есть аккордеон, пытаюсь добавить к нему стрелки состояния. При открытой вкладке ей присваивается класс `active`, далее пробую добавить класс, который перевернет изображение, но не понимаю как выловить именно эту открытую вкладку, поэтому изображения переворачиваются все.

PS перед всем этим так же через JS добавляется изображение, если это важно.

```js
var welement = document.body.querySelectorAll(".toggler");//родитель
var welementAdd = document.body.querySelectorAll(".toggler img");//добавленный ранее элемент

for(var i=0; i<welement.length;i++){//вещаем клик на всех родителей
    welement[i].addEventListener('click', selectAc);
}
function selectAc(){
    if(this.classList.contains('active')){//проверяем условие
        for(var i=0; i<welementAdd.length;i++){
             welementAdd[i].classList.add('active-ac-img');
        }
    }else {
        for(var i=0; i<welementAdd.length;i++){
             welementAdd[i].classList.remove('active-ac-img');
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.active-ac-img{
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion-item">
    <div class="toggler">
        <img src="/images/arr.png" width="30" height="28">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion-item">
    <div class="toggler">
        <img src="/images/arr.png" width="30" height="28">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion-item">
    <div class="toggler">
        <img src="/images/arr.png" width="30" height="28">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
// назначить обработчик click всем элементам .toggler
document.body.querySelectorAll(".toggler").forEach(
  toggler => toggler.addEventListener('click', selectAc));

function selectAc(){
  // убрать класс active-ac-img со всех картинок
  document.body.querySelectorAll(".toggler img").forEach(
    img => img.classList.remove('active-ac-img'));
  // добавить класс active-ac-img к картинке щелкнутого элемента
  this.querySelector("img").classList.add('active-ac-img');
}
```

```css
.active-ac-img{
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion-item">
    <div class="toggler">
        <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.png" width="50" height="50">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion-item">
    <div class="toggler">
        <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.png" width="50" height="50">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion-item">
    <div class="toggler">
        <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.png" width="50" height="50">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает. 
Тем не менее, могли бы прокомментировать код? Я его не очень понимаю, что тут и к чему)
Так же если мы производим клик на активную вкладку, то класс `active` убирается, но изображение не переворачивается.

Comment: @ВладЮдкин Мне трудно сказать что-либо про класс `"active"`, так как в вопросе он (и операции с ним) не фигурирует. Пример в ответе работает.

Comment: Ну вообще, он есть в условии вопроса. Операции с ним так же есть - проверка условия.

Comment: @ВладЮдкин Вы хотите сказать, что пример в вопросе демонстрирует описываемое поведение?

Comment: возможно, я Вас не так понял, но думаю что да. В любом случае, ваш код работает, но не понимаю как туда поставить это условие, подскажите?

Comment: @ВладЮдкин В какой момент элементам добавляется (удаляется) класс `active`?

Comment: При клике по блоку (родителю) с классом `.toggler`

Comment: @ВладЮдкин Почему Вы не хотите включить этот код в вопрос?